# How to handle case 0/0 when calculating average on grafana prometheus

Tags: spring, spring-boot, prometheus, grafana

My Spring boot application is exposing some Summary metrics like:

```
execution_duration_rest_endpoint_seconds_count{name="boundary",type="notification",eventType="rest_endpoint",uri="/test/4",} 2.0
execution_duration_rest_endpoint_seconds_sum{name="boundary",type="notification",eventType="rest_endpoint",uri="/test/4",} 2.026
```

I want to calculate the average latency and show the chart on Grafana dashboard. Bellow is my promql:

```
sum (increase(execution_duration_rest_endpoint_seconds_sum[$__interval]) / increase(execution_duration_rest_endpoint_seconds_count[$__interval])) by (name, type)
```

The chart is showing like:
[image: chart]

The yellow and green dot showing in the chart is the average of the latency grouped by name and type (when metrics come).

But when the system got idled for a while, means no request/metrics come, then the chart show nothing

I believe the reason behind is, when no request come, then the increase function return 0 for both `increase(execution_duration_rest_endpoint_seconds_sum[$__interval])` and `increase(execution_duration_rest_endpoint_seconds_count[$__interval])`, so it become sum (0/0) by (blabla) and the chart stuck there.

I want to ask you guy whether my promql is correct. If not, how to correct it? If it is correct, then how to handle case 0/0?

Thank you